# Cannot JDBC Connect 19y old Java to new SQL Server. It worked fine on old server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Cannot JDBC Connect 19y old Java to new SQL Server. It worked fine on old server.

Yep I tried JDBC install + following 18y old documentation (...) to install com ADO.net (yes adding Path) + making ODBC cnx (test OK) + SSMS conx OK etc BUUUT both (!) old winxp vm jre (worked FINE on old VPServer killed by Godaddy :( AND Also new Win10 machine...

error : see https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rswht9RQl3uim4cRDj_KwYemZ4GYNb7O
+ :

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>    Exception in SIMP_StoredProcedure.connect com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServer
>       Exception: TCP/IP-anslutningen till vΣrden  misslyckades. [= TCP/IP-CONNECTION to host failed.java.net.UnknownHostException:
>       Exception in SIMP_StoredProcedure.run java.lang.NullPointerException
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at se.lazybee.simp.SIMP_StoredProcedure.run(SIMP_StoredProcedure.java:13
>       1)
>               at SIMP_PageText.loadFromDB_A(SIMP_PageText.java:67)<>
>       at ....

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to connect to the correct server, "UnknownHostException" seems **clear** to me. Check `/etc/hosts` and dns entries; you might just be missing name resolution.

Comment: ?que? as said SSMS connects fine (and ODBC both 32 & 64 bit) to EXACT same new VPS. BUUT the Java doesnt connect(JDBC mssql)... Version/Upgrade issue?

Answer (score 0):

i SOLVED it myself: used double slash instead of single:  DATASOURCE = 11.x.y.z\\MSSQLSERVER works. NOT DATASOURCE = 11.x.y.z\MSSQLSERVER . wow